# Field Extension With Cube Root of 7

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I have the following problem that I am stuck on:

Consider the element $a=\sqrt[3]{7}$ of $\mathbf{R}$. Show that this element is algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}$ and find its minimal polynomial. Also, find the degree of the extension $[\mathbf{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7}\right):\mathbf{Q}]$ and find a basis of $\mathbf{Q}\left(\sqrt[3]{7}\right)$ over $\mathbf{Q}$.

My thoughts so far: I think that the minimal polynomial is $f(x)=x^{3}-7$. Is this correct? If so, how to I prove this is the minimal polynomial? Also, I think that the basis should be $\{1,\sqrt[3]{7},\sqrt[3]{49}\}$ based on some other examples I have seen. Is this correct? If so, could someone explain why this is the correct basis? If not, what is the basis?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Of course $f(x) = x^3-7$ has $\sqrt[3]{7}$ as a root, so you just need to show that $f$ is irreducible to show that it is indeed the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{7}$.  What irreducibility tests do you know?

Also, your basis is correct.  Suppose we have an algebraic extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/ \mathbb{Q}$.  If the degree of the extension is $n$, then $\{\alpha^k\}_{k=0}^{n-1}$ serves as a basis.

*Proof*:  Suppose we could write $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k \alpha^k = 0$ for $c_k \in \mathbb{Q}$ not all zero.  Then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_kx^k$ is a polynomial for which $\alpha$ is a root: a contradiction because the minimal polynomial for $\alpha$ must have degree $n = [ \mathbb{Q}(\alpha) : \mathbb{Q}]$.  Furthermore, that we must have $c_k = 0$ for all $0 \leq k \leq n-1$ [demonstrates the linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition) of the set $\{\alpha^k\}_{k=0}^{n-1}$.  The cardinality of that linearly independent set is equal to the degree of the extension, so we can rest assured that it is indeed a basis for the extension**.

---

**Just to drive home fundamentally important ideas: recall that  the *degree of an extension* $K/F$ is defined to be the *dimension* of $K$ when $K$ is viewed as a vector space over $F$.  The *dimension* of a vector space over a field is defined to be the cardinality of a given basis for the vector space.  And [it is a theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces) that all possible bases of a vector space have equal cardinality, and that any linearly independent set of vectors with that cardinality is necessarily a basis.

Comment: That helps! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help @A.S.Hopkins.  I fixed some minor typos, wherein I had $k=1$ instead of $k=0$ as the bounds in the summation, and I had written $\alpha_k$ instead of $\alpha^k$ in a couple spots.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a$ is clearly a root of $f$, it's enough to show that $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $f$ is cubic, it suffices to show that $f$ has no roots in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I figured that part out already. Is this all we have to do to show that it is the minimal polynomial? Like nothing else to show uniqueness or anything?

Comment: The uniqueness of the minimal polynomial follows from the definition.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. How would you determine the basis of the extension?